# Why Variable is not working with condition

Tags: bash

I don't know what's happend with this code. Variable "VALUE=true" but can't see why can't access to the first condition:

```
VALUE=$(curl -s http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/${LIGHT} | jq --compact-output -C '.state.on')
echo $VALUE

if [ "${VALUE}" = "true" ]; then
  echo "${VALUE} | on | Active=1"
else
  echo "${VALUE} | off | Active=0"
fi
```

The result of this is:

```
true
true | off | Active=0
```

Why VALUE not's "true" and can't goes to the first condition?

```
+ VALUE='true'
+ echo 'true'
true
+ '[' 'true' = true ']'
+ echo 'true | off | Active=0'
true | off | Active=0
```

As we can see no spaces on VALUE

```
+ VALUE='true'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'true'` != `true`

Comment: I don't have enough info to reproduce your `curl` call but if I start with `VALUE="true"` and then run your `if/then/else/fi` block, I get the correct answer => `true | on | Active=1`; this leads me to think the `curl` call may be returning something in addition to the string `true` (eg, spaces? non-printable character?) we need to see the actual value returned by the `curl` call; after the `curl` call consider adding  `echo "${VALUE}" | od -c` (or @thatotherguy's `printf '%q\n' "${VALUE}"`) and post the result

Answer (score 6):

In HTML terms, you are comparing `<span>foo</span>` with `foo`, and get confused that they don't match because they both look identical on the page.

It's a tragedy that `set -x` doesn't clarify this. Here are some other ways to examine the real value:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$VALUE"
$'\E[0;39mtrue\E[0m'

$ printf '%s\n' "$VALUE" | cat -vE
^[[0;39mtrue^[[0m$
```

You get this gunk instead of `true` because you asked `jq` for colorized output. Simply remove the `-C` (and maybe add `-r`) to get plaintext output.